# fatal error: call to a member function prepare on a non-object

Tags: php

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to why the following piece of code is failing..

**MySQLDb.php:**

```
class MySQLDb 
{
        protected $_mysql; 
        protected $_query;


        function __constructor($host,$username,$password,$db)
        {
            $this->_mysql = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$db) or die('Problem connecting to the DB.');

        }


        function query($query)
        {
            $this->_query =  filter_var($query,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->_dynamicBindResult($stmt);
        }


 protected function _prepareQuery(){

            $dbh = $this->_mysql;
            if ( !$stmt = $dbh->prepare($this->_query) ) {
                trigger_error('Problem preparing query', E_USER_ERROR);

            }

            return $stmt;
        }
```

**index.php:**

```
require_once('MYSQLDb.php');

$Db = new MySQLDb('localhost','root','','blog');


$results =$Db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
```

When I run the program it spits out the error `fatal error: call to a member function prepare on a non-object` at `if ( !$stmt = $dbh->prepare($this->_query) ) {`

I'm trying to learn the object oriented way of doing this things so not very clued in on how to troubleshoot this.

thanks.

Comment: `new mysqli()` won't return false like the old `mysql_connect()`, so your `or die()` won't be triggered. You need to do `if (mysqli_connect_error()) { die (mysqli_connect_error()); }`  This is likely a connection problem, but your error handling doesn't do what you expect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your constructor:

```
function __constructor($host,$username,$password,$db) {
```

The actual PHP "class constructor" name is [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), not `__constructor`, so your version is never being called and `$this->_mysql` is `null` (i.e. - not an object).

Try update the function to the following and it should work:

```
function __construct($host,$username,$password,$db) {
```